# Error running Spring Boot applications on Bluemix

Tags: java, spring, ibm-cloud

I created a spring starter app using http://start.spring.io/, downloaded the zip, compiled using `mvn install` and pushed the jar to Bluemix :

`cf push myspringapp1155 -p target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

The application does not start. The output of

`cf logs myspringapp1155 --recent` shows:

```
2015-07-10T11:13:30.25-0400 [App/0]      ERR Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=demo/DemoApplication, offset=6
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jar, war and ear files on Bluemix are handled by the Liberty buildpack by default on Bluemix. The Liberty buildpack currently uses Java 1.7 (This might change soon). You can either:

- Compile your source using 1.7. Edit your pom.xml 
  `<java.version>1.7</java.version>` or
- Use the JBP_CONFIG_OPENJDK environment variable to specify an alternative version of the JRE. For example, to use the OPENJDK 8 set the following environment variable:
  `$ cf set-env myapp JBP_CONFIG_OPENJDK "version: 1.8.+"`

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix now supports 1.8 in Liberty build pack. Hence simple cf push command can deploy the app into bluemix using Liberty java.